# Django: How to identify if object is connected through ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

A basic representation from my models:

```
class CarType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cartype = models.ManyToManyField(CarType)
    
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a search function where the CarType is readily provided. I would have this object by it's ID.

The customer is connected to the brand, which has manytomany to cartype (please ignore the models in this case, they are for illustration purpose).

**In my query, I only want to return those customers, which are connected to a brand, which on its turn has a relation with the cartype from a many-to-many relationship.**

So basically; how do I filter the customers to show only those, where the brand has a relation with the cartype?

What my current thought is:

- Is it possible to create a modelmanager of some sort, which accepts the CarType as argument and return all relevant customers
- Create a second model for customers, where records are stored with a foreignkey directly to cartype (perhaps trigger this when a customer is added)
- Add a manytomanyfield for CarType to Customer, which automatically creates all the manytomany relations based on the existing records available in brand (and run a cronjob to review/update these relations based on changes in the Brand model/object).

I need the query to be as universal and "simple" as possible, but this one leaves me stranded.

### Edit

To add a little more context: I'm trying to build a cascading form, based on criteria stored in a dictionary. This way, I should be able to easily recycle my code for different forms, where data is used in different combinations.

Below is how I currently do the query. Which works on a simple model, searching straightforward for text in columns (for foreignkey this is through e.g. country__name).

In certain searches the foreign key, when already provided, should limit the query. So I am trying to fit in the logic mentioned helpfully below, to be able to limit the query to the those records where recursively the object X is met.

```
            ### Initialize Q filter
            filter_q = Q()
            for x in columns:
                filter_q |= Q(**{f'{x}__icontains': val})
                
            headers = forms[htmx_form]['headers']
            fields = forms[htmx_form]['columns']
            fields.append('pk')
            
            id_model = django.apps.apps.get_model(forms[htmx_form]['app'], forms[htmx_form]['model'])
            results = id_model.objects.filter(filter_q).distinct()[:10]
            results = results.values(*fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code but you should be able to just traverse through the models.

You fetch a car type:

```py
car_type = CarType.objects.get(pk=1) # Example, this should be your code where you retrieve your car type
```

And then you can use this `car_type` to filter a queryset of `Customer`:

```py
customers = Customer.objects.filter(brand__cartype__in=car_type)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems so much easier than I was even aware of. Is it also possible to do this with Django Q?

Comment: All filters can be put in a Q-object, which can be given to the filter function. `q_filter = Q(brand__cartype__in=car_type)`

Comment: if parent: filter_q &= Q(**{brand__cartype__in: val}) something in this direction I should look for I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter directly on the name with:

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(brand__cartype__name__icontains='Ford')
```